# php exec() - git push origin master not working, but other git commands are working 

Tags: php, git

I used below code :

```
    echo exec("git add . ");  //this is working  
echo exec("git commit -am 'first commit' "); //also working  
echo exec("git push origin master");  //NOT WORKING, also not showing any error .
```

I chowned folder permissions from user to www-data . So, some git commands are working but

```
GIT PUSH ORIGIN MASTER
```

is not working from php exec . What is the solution ? 
Also, please tell me why PUSH in exec NOT showing any error or msg, how can i see those msgs . 
Also,if possible, please provide me any good links for more advanced use of git commands from php exec .

Update : 
I also tried this : I added post-commit hook by creating file .git/hooks/post-commit

I added this code to it :

```
git push origin master
```

But I didnt get any msg or error after commiting, it just commited but didnt do any push.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try `git push origin master` normally via `terminal`? What was the result? BTW, which directory is it getting executed?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but have you looked at [PHP bindings for libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/php-git)?

Comment: No I didnt check PHP bindings . And Mr. Praveen ,  it is getting executed at /var/www/fd/index.php . I tried it using terminal and got permission denied (public key) error when using sudo . And without using sudo, it pushed but failed writing resullt to git as sudo is required to write data in that folder(as i chowned as www-data)

Answer (score 2):

I assume the push command will try to push to a **remote** repository (i.e. not another folder on your system but a remote server behind SSH/HTTPS).

In this case you are most likely missing a HTTPS client certificate HTTPS or an SSH key. Your webserver (and therefore PHP) most likely runs as a different user and does not have access to the private key. Next to that if the private key needs a password it will not work because the exec command is not an interactive session.

Anyway I heavily recommend you to use some sort of bindings and not calling the binaries. Any direct call will start a new process and this is way more inefficient that calls into a library.

Comment: This is a good answer. It answered the commit and push. One needs the permission of the web server (apache) which on linux is 'www-data'. There will be a .ssh directory created in /var/www and it needs your id_rsa (or other keys) as read/write to www-data. Also the .git directory and its contents to be read/write to group www-data. Permissions can be a real conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked which branch your are on?
'git status' will tell you.

I'd also recommend working on a branch and not directly on master.

> git branch dev_test
>
> git checkout dev_test
>
> git add .
>
> git commit -a -m "first comment"
>
> git push origin dev_test
>
> git checkout master
>
> git merge dev_test
>
> git push origin master

Comment: # On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)